# How do I add an Onion-Location header with Caddy2?

Tags: caddy

How do I add an `Onion-Location` header to all my pages in Caddy2 the value of which is `$string+request_path`

> Onion-Location is an easy way to advertise an onion site to the users. You can either configure a web server to show an Onion-Location Header or add an HTML meta attribute in the website.
>
> — [Tor Project](https://community.torproject.org/onion-services/advanced/onion-location/)

The example Nginx configuration shows:

```
add_header Onion-Location http://<your-onion-address>.onion$request_uri;
```

I think they meant path, rather than full URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
header Onion-Location http://whatevercrypticname.onion{path}
```

If you have the `$TOR_HOSTNAME` saved as an environment variable then use

```
header Onion-Location http://{$TOR_HOSTNAME}{path}
```